# Selecting every other parent’s child

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have an HTML template like this:

```
<div id = "container">

   <div class = "status">
      <div class ="dynamic"></div>
   </div>

   <div class = "status">
      <div class ="dynamic"></div>
   </div>

   <div class = "status">
      <div class ="dynamic"></div>
   </div>

   <div class = "status">
      <div class ="dynamic"></div>
   </div>

</div>
```

Is there way to change the background of every other `.status`'s `.dynamic`, using CSS or jQuery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this in pure CSS:

```css
#container > .status:nth-child(2n+1) > .dynamic {
    /* Change the background */
}
```

[(Here’s a demo!)](http://codepen.io/minitech/pen/Lpxzr)

Answer (score 1):

This can be done through CSS:

```css
#container > .status:nth-child(2n) > .dynamic { background: whatever-you-want; }
```

or

```css
#container > .status:nth-child(2n+1) > .dynamic { background: whatever-you-want; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$('.status:odd .dynamic').css('color', 'blue')
```

or

```
$('.dynamic:even').css('color', 'blue')
```

Demo: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/A7qjF/)